# Import JS to Vue from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

Forgive my lack of expertise, but I am attempting to integrate and import This [Grid System](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) Into my own Vue Setup and Im having some slight trouble. Now, I normally import Plugins like so:

```
import VuePlugin from 'vue-plugin'

Vue.use(VuePlugin)
```

and I'm then able to use the components of said plugin globally, however this is not a plugin and I'm having trouble pulling in/importing the needed components into my own components... suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### If you use it via NPM:

First, install:

```
npm install --save vue-grid-layout
```

Then "register" it (probably a `.vue` - or `.js` - file):

```
import VueGridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout'

export default {
  ...
  components: {
    'GridLayout': VueGridLayout.GridLayout,
    'GridItem': VueGridLayout.GridItem
  }
```

#### If you use it via `<script>` tag:

Naturally, add it somewhere:

```
<script src="some-cdn-or-folder/vue-grid-layout.min.js"></script>
```

And "register" it (propably a `.js` file or another `<script>` tag):

```
var GridLayout = VueGridLayout.GridLayout;
var GridItem = VueGridLayout.GridItem;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        "GridLayout": GridLayout,
        "GridItem": GridItem
    },
```

---

#### And... in your templates

In both cases, you can then use `<grid-layout ...></grid-layout>` in your template.

Comment: thanks, that did it. however i was wondering, is there anyway to make the component definition cleaner by doing something like `import VueGridLayout.GridLayout as GridLayout from 'vue-grid-layout'` and then defining it in my components as just `components: { GridLayout, ... }`

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm assuming the `VueGridLayout` is the default import, and you can't destructure those. You could declare a `const GridLayout = VueGridLayout.GridLayout`, but I believe that's what you are trying to run away from...